LibVLCSharp.UWP not playing local audio file
I'm simply trying to play an audio file ex. an .mp3 from local folder or from //Assets folder. Anything that i'm missing? I also tried the official sample project LibVLCSharp.UWP.sample also not working. With online url there is no problem, only local paths.
I already tried with diffrent combinations of paths, also necessary permissions("ms-settings:privacy-broadfilesystemaccess") and still nothing.
Regarding the permisions i can play with the uwp MediaPlayer local files with no pb. Thank you for your feedback.
private void Initialize(InitializedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
LibVLC = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs: true, eventArgs.SwapChainOptions);
MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(LibVLC);
// var uri = new Uri("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-   bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4");
// var uri = new Uri("http://streams.90s90s.de/techno/mp3-128/radiode/");
var uri = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/b2_forgiveness_of_sins-drum.mp3");
string filePath = @"C:\Users\drago\Music\b2-dj_hell--let_no_man_jack_(abe_duque_mix)-cmc.mp3";
using var media = new Media(LibVLC, @"ms-appx:///Assets/b2_forgiveness_of_sins-drum.mp3");
MediaPlayer.Play(media);
}


maybe try with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile?view=winrt-22621
